# Format string attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, format-string

I was exploring format strings in python and came across manual field specification with integers to identify positional arguments.

As far as I know, format string supports only two operators: `.` (getattr) and `[]` (getitem)

But when I try to use it, I am getting an error.

```
"The story of a {0} {1.upper()}".format("cunning", "fox")
```

This gives

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'upper()'
```

However, when I do this:

```
"The story of a {0} {1.upper}".format("cunning", "fox")
```

It gives the output:
`The story of a cunning <built-in method upper of str object at 0x7f65756e1e18>`

Can someone please explain why is this happening? What am I missing here?

Answer (score -1):

Use the new [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) introduced in Python 3.6. If you are learning Python now, that is your best choice.

```
a = "cunning"
b = "fox"
print(f"The story of a {a} {b.upper()}")
```

Also `print(f"The story of a {'cunning'} {'fox'.upper()}")` will work, but what is the advantage of using string formatting if you don't use it with variables?

Comment: not, however, an answer to the question

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of `f-strings` and am not looking for a workaround. This question is just for this use case, as of why is python throwing that error, when it can figure out that there is a builtin function that exists.